# An approximation for the sum of k largest elements of n-sorted arrays?

Tags: algorithms, approximation

Suppose we want to find the sum of the $k$ largest elements of $n$-sorted arrays. All arrays are containing $k$ elements.

All elements are between 0 and 1, and the the sum of all elements in array $i$ equals to $S_i$.

Instead of  using a min-heap to find the $k$ largest elements (and thus, deriving the sum of the $k$ largest elements), one way for approximating the sum is to select the $k \cdot \frac{S_i} { {\sum_{i=1}^n} S_i} $ largest elements from array $i$.

We assume that $k \cdot \frac{S_i} { {\sum_{i=1}^n} S_i} $ is an integer, for every $i$.

Is the above algorithm is a constant-factor approximation algorithm? I think it is 0.5-approximation algorithm, but not sure yet.

Note that if the arrays have arbitrarily array sizes, then the claim is not true. For example, if there are $n=2$ arrays, one with $k$ elements equal to $1$, and the other with $k \cdot t^2$ elements of $1/t$, then while the sum of the $k$ largest elements is equal to $k$, the approximation will approach to $0$, as $t$ approaches to infinity. This why we assume that the array sizes are both equal to $k$.

Comment: Well, how about trying to prove it?

Comment: I have tried, not succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried easier cases, such as small $k$ or $n$? You can start with $k=1$, $k=2$, $n=1$, $n=2$, and so on.

Comment: Of course!
I first tried to disproved the claim, by giving counter examples, but not succeed.
However, for k=1,2 the claim holds. As well as for n=1.
For n=2, I am not sure yet...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus do you have any hint on this? I am trying to solve this  problem for weeks. Will appreciate any direction on this problem.

Comment: The approximation can be arbitrarily bad if the array sizes are not the same. Take n-1 arrays with one element equal to 1, and one array with 20n elements equal to 0.1. You need to account for the array size in your formula.

Comment: We assume that all arrays have the same size

Comment: If the arrays have arbitrarily  array sizes, then even if there are 2 arrays, one with $k$ elements equal to 1, and the other with $k\cdot t^2$ elements of $1/t$,  then while the sum of the $k$ largest elements is equal to $k$,  the approximation will approach to 0, as $t$ approaches to infinity.

This why we assume that  the array sizes are not the same. and we select $k$ elements from $n$ arrays containing $k$ elements.

Comment: With constant array size, the solution can still be arbitrarily bad. Let n = 2k. k arrays with one element = 1, 99 elements = 0, S = 1. k arrays with 100 elements = 0.1, S = 10. You will pick lots of the 0.1 elements. I saw you changed the number of elements to k: Still arbitrarily bad if k is large.